# How to slowdown/bottleneck `fs.createReadStream` data event for debugging

Tags: node.js, websocket, stream, fs

I have `fs` read stream what firing `data` event for file chunks. Is there a way to bottlenext this event firing to be able to debug it? I want to make progress bar on client (Stream is sending data by websockets to client), but everything is so fast, that I am unable to actually test it.

```
 const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./test.jpg", { encoding: "binary" });
    const chunks = [];

    readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
      // Emit chunk to connected socket
      socket.emit("data-chunk", chunk);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Pause the stream and then resume it after a delay:

```
readStream.on("data", function (chunk) {
      // Emit chunk to connected socket
      socket.emit("data-chunk", chunk);

      readStream.pause();
      setTimeout(function () { readStream.resume(); }, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pause to your *ReadStream* event handler to slow it down:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./test.jpg", { encoding: "binary" });

readStream.on("data", async (chunk) => {
  // Emit chunk to connected socket
  socket.emit("data-chunk", chunk);
  await sleep(1000);
});
```